# Angular UI customization issue. Languages and Breadcrumb specifically. I want to remove them

Tags: angular, abp

I want to remove Languages and Breadcrumb. As per documentation it's done like this

```
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private navItems: NavItemsService) {
    navItems.removeItem(eThemeBasicComponents.Languages);
    ...
  }
}
```

But it didn't work. Both for Languages and Breadcrumb is still there. I don't know if it is bug or I'm missing something.
Then I tried this

```
constructor(private replaceableComponents: ReplaceableComponentsService) 
{
    replaceableComponents.add({
      component: DummyComponent, // just empty component
      key: eThemeLeptonXComponents.Languages,
    });
    ...
}
```

DummyComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  template: '',
})
export class DummyComponent {}
```

tried null instead of DummyComponent. Both versions seems to work identically. But when I login both items appears until I click somewhere and than it disappears. Any ideas?